# sql join with multiple cases

Tags: sql, case

I have this join

```
INNER JOIN Table2 A 
        ON T.Field1=A.Field1 
       and a.Field2= (CASE WHEN t.Field_iso is null THEN 'Value' ELSE t.Field_iso END)
```

what I additionally want to add is if field 2 is not equal to above case then try `a.Field2=t.Field_iso2`

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: The CASE expression can be simplified to `coalesce(t.field_iso, 'Value')`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `coalesce`

```
INNER JOIN Table2 A 
ON T.Field1=A.Field1
where a.Field2 = coalesce(t.Field_iso, 'Value') or a.Field2 = t.field_iso2
```